# setInterval() timings are... off?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm baffled by this... but it appears my overly-complex system of setInterval() lines, is off a tad. Maybe the timings are trying to catch up? It's just a little weird and I'm not sure why.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dr3amTw1st/HV3fA/embedded/result/

```
var number=0; // Do not change!
var key1=true, key2=false, key3=false, key4=false, key5=false; // Do not change!
var key6=false, key7=false, key8=false, key9=false; // Do not change!
var climbSpeed=2000; // Climbing speed in milliseconds. Don't change unless you REALLY know what you're doing.
var raised=100; // The amount raised so far. Able to be changed.
var goal=250; // The goal, obviously... :P Able to be changed.

var c1=setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML="$"+number++;},climbSpeed);
var c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10;

var check=setInterval(
function() {
    if (number>0 && key1==true) {
        key1=false;
        clearInterval(c1);
        climbSpeed=1500;
        c2=setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML="$"+number++;},climbSpeed);
        key2=true;
    }
    if (number>3 && key2==true) {
        key2=false;
        clearInterval(c2);
        climbSpeed=700;
        c3=setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML="$"+number++;},climbSpeed);
        key3=true;
    }
    if (number>9 && key3==true) {
        key3=false;
        clearInterval(c3);
        climbSpeed=200;
        c4=setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML="$"+number++;},climbSpeed);
        key4=true;
    }
    if (number>(.15*raised) && key4==true) {
        key4=false;
        clearInterval(c4);
        climbSpeed=100;
        c5=setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML="$"+number++;},climbSpeed);
        key5=true;
    }
    if (number>(.20*raised) && key5==true) {
        key5=false;
        clearInterval(c5);
        climbSpeed=90;
        c6=setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML="$"+number++;},climbSpeed);
        key6=true;
    }
    if (number>(.30*raised) && key6==true) {
        key6=false;
        clearInterval(c6);
        climbSpeed=110;
        c7=setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML="$"+number++;},climbSpeed);
        key7=true;
    }
    if (number>(raised-20) && key7==true) {
        key7=false;
        clearInterval(c7);
        climbSpeed=500;
        c8=setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML="$"+number++;},climbSpeed);
        key8=true;
    }
    if (number>(raised-11) && key8==true) {
        key8=false;
        clearInterval(c8);
        climbSpeed=650;
        c9=setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML="$"+number++;},climbSpeed);
        key9=true;
    }
    if (number>=(raised-10) && key9==true) {
        key9=false;
        clearInterval(c9);
        climbSpeed=900;
        c10=setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML="$"+number++;},climbSpeed);
    }
    if (number>raised) {
        clearInterval(c10);
        document.getElementById("amount").style.color="red";
        //document.getElementById("amount").style.fontSize="250px";
    }
},climbSpeed);

function stop() {
alert("climbSpeed: " + climbSpeed + "\n" + "number: " + number + "\n" + "raised: " + raised);
//clearInterval(c1);
//clearInterval(c2);
//clearInterval(c3);
//clearInterval(c4);
//clearInterval(c5);
//clearInterval(c6);
//clearInterval(c7);
//clearInterval(c8);
//clearInterval(c9);
//clearInterval(c10);
}
```

The jsfiddle above looks a little off as far as the css goes, but I think that's just jsfiddle itself. It looks fine when I run it all as one document in google chrome (And I've only made it to run in google chrome). This is a one time application to be used on my own computer, once, as a fund raiser thermometer. So only pay attention to the number and the javascript. I just want the numbers to look smoother. I thought about using percentages (.90*raised), but they have pretty much the same effect. What's going on here with my timings and my climbSpeed? Also, the buttons at the top are just for debugging purposes. They won't be in the final draft of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `setInterval` multiple times, and it's repeating every 2s. After next 2s you make another `setInterval` logic part, so it's running double `setInterval` function. If you wish to change numbers in save interval, than use single `setTimout` function.

Comment: I am using multiple setInterval()'s, but clearing each one and starting a new one before the next one begins, correct? I don't quite understand.

Comment: @Dr3amTw1st You are clearing inner `setInterval`, but outer `check` interval is repeated. And check if you are really clearing all intervals that you have set so far. Better clear them all at the beginning of function.